How to Configure Nginx to Serve a Kotlin Multiplatform Project Wasm Website Built with Gradle?
I am working with a Kotlin Multiplatform project that you can view here on GitHub. I started by using the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard and selected the Web platform option, everything else remains unchanged.
Here's what I've done:

Ran the ./gradlew build command.
When I attempt to open the index.html file directly, either one of this directories,the page remains blank.
However, when I run ./gradlew wasmJsBrowserProductionWebpack, the site launches successfully and is served by the WebPack server.

I would like to serve this project using Nginx instead of WebPack. Could someone advise on the necessary Gradle build configurations to generate a directory structure that Nginx can use effectively?
Additionally, I would appreciate guidance on setting up the nginx.conf file for this purpose.

You need to share the relevant gradle files here so we can take a look. Make sure it is a [mre]. Links to code hosted on external sites isn't sufficient, see [ask] (section "Help others reproduce the problem").

Assuming you want to deploy static Compose website (The only way to use Compose for currently), you first need to execute the following command in your project ./gradlew module:wasmJsBrowserDistribution. Where module could be composeApp. This will generate output files in build/dist/wasmJs/productionExecutable folder.
You can then place these files under /var/www/your-site/ folder and then configure nginx to serve those files.
